# how to create 30 minutes time slots in flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart

How to create time slots in flutter / dart?

I want to make a list of 30 minutes time slots from given start time and end time.

Example:
start time 9:00 AM
end Time is 10:00 PM
list will be

```
List<String> timeSlots = ['9:30 AM','10:00 AM','10:30 AM','11:00 AM'....]
```

Is there any library to solve this problem?

Comment: did you try something yet?

Comment: I have no idea about it.

Comment: convert both 'start time' and 'end time' into 24 hr unit, then (endTime-StartTime)/0.5 = number of slots.

Comment: @Darish please explain with an example.

Comment: what kind of output you want?

Comment: i want to show in drop down list something like 12:00 PM

Comment: so if you want a drop down list, first read `DropdownButton` class official documentation

Comment: i want `List<String>` @Darish

Comment: and if you want those strings read `DateFormat` class official documentation

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can create this with a generator, though the syntax is a little ugly since the `TimeOfDay` class added by Flutter isn't very powerful:

```dart
Iterable<TimeOfDay> getTimes(TimeOfDay startTime, TimeOfDay endTime, Duration step) sync* {
  var hour = startTime.hour;
  var minute = startTime.minute;

  do {
    yield TimeOfDay(hour: hour, minute: minute);
    minute += step.inMinutes;
    while (minute >= 60) {
      minute -= 60;
      hour++;
    }
  } while (hour < endTime.hour ||
           (hour == endTime.hour && minute <= endTime.minute));
}
```

Usage:

```dart
final startTime = TimeOfDay(hour: 9, minute: 0);
final endTime = TimeOfDay(hour: 22, minute: 0);
final step = Duration(minutes: 30);

final times = getTimes(startTime, endTime, step)
                .map((tod) => tod.format(context))
                .toList();

print(times);

// Results:
// [9:00 AM, 9:30 AM, 10:00 AM, 10:30 AM, 11:00 AM, 11:30 AM, 12:00 PM, 12:30 PM, 1:00 PM, 1:30 PM, 2:00 PM, 2:30 PM, 3:00 PM, 3:30 PM, 4:00 PM, 4:30 PM, 5:00 PM, 5:30 PM, 6:00 PM, 6:30 PM, 7:00 PM, 7:30 PM, 8:00 PM, 8:30 PM, 9:00 PM, 9:30 PM, 10:00 PM]
```

Comment: *"... since the TimeOfDay class added by Flutter isn't very powerful"* you can use `DateTime` instead

Comment: @pskink OP specifically stated they are working with times of the day, which is what makes `TimeOfDay` appropriate. Unless they actually need the date component as well, I don't think they should use it as it comes with a fair amount of extra data you need to sort of hand-wave away, which is generally a sign of code smell.

Comment: `var base = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(11 * Duration.millisecondsPerHour);
var list = List.generate(10, (index) => base.add(Duration(minutes: 30) * index))
  .map((dt) => DateFormat.jm().format(dt));
list.forEach(print);` - just 3 lines of code

Comment: @pskink That string now includes a bunch of unnecessary data that OP doesn't want, like year, month, day, seconds, 24-hour times, time zone offset, etc. And formatting it so it does match what OP wants is being wasteful with data and will include an obtuse formatting string that hurts readability. Making code shorter doesn't always make it better.

Comment: *"That string now includes a bunch of unnecessary data ... "* what data? that string includes `12:00 PM, 12:30 PM, 1:00 PM` etc, tried to run those 3 lines of code? you are generating list of `TimeOfDay` objects in a weird way and i am generating list of `DateTime` objects - its the only difference

Comment: @pskink My mistake, I didn't see the `jm()` part of the code. You'd think SO of all places would have a less stupid way of embedding code in comments.

Answer (score -1):

**Create a list with length :** [List.generate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/List.generate.html)

```
List<String>.generate(3, (int index) => "time ${index + 1}"); 
// ["time 1", "time 2", "time 3"]
```

Comment: This creates a list, but the question asked for making time slots for a given time period